# Attack move in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there a way to bind your normal attacks to something like League of Legends Attack Move?

This means that I target the closest visible target near my cursor that is in range. Which means if an enemy is behind me but in range and I click in front of me that I will attack that enemy.

In League I can easily kite because of this attack move but in Diablo I cannot. Mostly because most models are smaller which make me miss click more often then I'd like. So I was hoping that I could bind a key to do this. If there is some setting file I can try to fiddle with that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no strict equivalent of RTS-style "attack move" in Diablo 3. The control scheme in Diablo 3 is tuned for more active combat, where RTS-style games originally had to accommodate the ability to command many, many units. LoL's history, as a game based off a mod for an RTS game, has led it to adopt these RTS style controls which aren't necessarily ideal for an action game where you control a single hero.

In Diablo, everything your character does is the result of a manual action taken by the player. If you don't issue attack commands, then your character will just stand motionless while enemies surround and kill him. This lack of inherent ability to attack means that "attack-move" as a concept can't really mean anything in Diablo.

tl;dr: **No**, there is no option for this at all.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I may have worded it a bit bad but for LoL I use the "A" key for Attack move. This way I can switch between them. Also, I'm pretty sure LoL wasn't based on an RTS game. I think you mean DotA2 as you can still command multiple units there.

Comment: Anyway, seems I have to spam the "force standstill" key so I don't accidentely walk towards enemies if I miss click.

Comment: @Gnarly404 LoL is based on Dota, which was a mod in WC3, which is an RTS game, so LoL's history is in RTS games, even if it doesn't qualify itself.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau As much as I like LoL, I do believe its gameplay would be better with a more Diablo-like control scheme. There are pros and cons, though, so it's definitely a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Gnarly404 pro-tip : bind force standstill to spacebar, this way you can just keep it pressed with your thumb, and keep the attack (mouse?) pressed too, you don't need to release the force stand nor the attack to use other spells.

Comment: @Rod Already have and that works fine when just standing still. But if I try to kite (move, attack, repeat) I have to mash it like a madman. With low attack speed it's not that bad, but I prefer not doing that with high attack speeds.

Comment: @Gnarly404 there is also a "force move" key, on use it override "force stand still" :
press stand still + attack > press force move to move a bit, release force move > you will continue to attack with force stand still.
that's basically how I play with my carnevil wd :P